# How can I make the search engine work for multibyte characters (Japanese in particular) in bookdown gitbook?

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown, multibyte, gitbook

I have built a gitbook with the **bookdown** package. The search engine does work for English-written parts of the text and codes (i.e. alphabet and numbers, basically), but I have found it doesn't work at all if I type in some Japanese words.

Is there any ways to make that work?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a feature that I'm interested in but don't have time to implement. Anyway, you may file a feature request to the Github repo https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I have filed a feature request. https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/792#issue-514114547

Answer (score 0):

This problem will be gone if you switch the search engine to `fuse` ([details here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-bookdown-version-023)):

```yaml
output:
  bookdown::gitbook:
    config:
      search:
        engine: fuse
```

Currently you need to install the dev version of **bookdown**:

```r
remotes::install_github('rstudio/bookdown')
```